# Improving performance of outer apply

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-performance

Let me briefly describe what I'm attempting in case someone has a much more elegant way of solving the same problem. I'm trying to write a stored procedure that looks at sales orders in a database, find when the same item is ordered by the same customer multiple times, and predict the next date of an order using an average of the previous intervals between orders for the same item. The query below is going to form the basis for the temp table to work against with probably cursors and running averages.

So far the query I have looks like this

```
SELECT    sl.custaccount ,
        sl.itemid ,
        sl.shippingdaterequested ,
        nextdate.shippingdaterequested AS nextshippingdaterequested
FROM      salesline AS sl
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                sl2.custaccount ,
                                sl2.itemid ,
                                sl2.shippingdaterequested
                      FROM      salesline AS sl2
                      WHERE     sl2.shippingdaterequested > sl.shippingdaterequested
                                AND sl2.custaccount = sl.custaccount
                                AND sl2.itemid = sl.itemid
                      GROUP BY  sl2.custaccount ,
                                sl2.itemid ,
                                sl2.shippingdaterequested
                      ORDER BY  sl2.shippingdaterequested
                    ) AS nextdate
GROUP BY  sl.custaccount ,
        sl.itemid ,
        sl.shippingdaterequested ,
        nextdate.shippingdaterequested
```

This query gives me a row for every sales line with a column representing the next time that item was ordered by that customer. If that column is NULL, I know the record I'm on is the last time.

The basic problem is that this query is way too slow, it runs fine if I go against a single customer at a time, returning results in a second, but running against ~100,000 customers would take around 27 hours.

I know the basic problem is that I'm outer applying, so it's probably doing row by agonizing row processing, but I'm not sure of another way to get to hear that would work out faster. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it more complex than it needs to be.
Just take the min and max and divide by the count

```
SELECT  sl.custaccount ,
    sl.itemid ,
    MAX(sl.shippingdaterequested) AS lastShip ,
    DATEDIFF(dd, MIN(sl.shippingdaterequested),
             MAX(sl.shippingdaterequested)) / COUNT(*) AS interval ,
    DATEADD(dd,
            DATEDIFF(dd, MIN(sl.shippingdaterequested),
                     MAX(sl.shippingdaterequested)) / COUNT(*),
            MAX(sl.shippingdaterequested)) AS nextShip
FROM    salesline AS sl
GROUP BY sl.custaccount ,
    sl.itemid
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```